# Как повысить права C# Linux

Tags: c#, linux, .net-core

Надо в определенный момент работы программы установить в операционку корневой сертификат.
Соответственно для этого нужно повысить права до суперпользователя.

Первое что приходит в голову - команда "SUDO".
Но: пользователь работает в GNOME и соотвественно как он будет вводить пароль не понятно.

Есть какая-то стратегия как это сделать?

Comment: запускать программу сразу из под sudo?

Comment: pkexec? . . . .

Comment: >*запускать программу сразу из под sudo? * 
Не получится - это компонента расширения браузера - и браузе запускае ее со своими правами...

Comment: @andreymal _pkexec?_
O! Правильно я понял что "pkexec" это фишка GNOME? Она есть во всех версиях?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/254072/110559